# How to aggregate objects in mongodb in same collection using _id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

For eg my collection has data:

```
const categories=[
      {
        name:"1",
        _id:"100",
        parentCategory:null
      },
      {
        name:"2",
        _id:"101",
        parentCategory:'100'
      },
      {
        name:"3",
        _id:"103",
        parentCategory:'101'
      },
      {
        name:"4",
        _id:"104",
        parentCategory:'100'
      }
 ]
```

I want result data to be aggregated with subcategories inserted into array for 6-7 levels

Sample result needed:

```
[{name:'1',
  _id:'100',
  subCategories:[
    {
       name:'2',
       _id:'101',
       subCategories:[{
                 name:'3',
                 _id:'103'
                }
    },
    {
      name:'4',
      _id:'104'
   }
}
]
```

How can this be achieved using mongodb lookup funnction or any other function

Comment: i think, its better to handle it with a function, because it will costed you to much. but you may wanna tell us why do you need output like that?

Comment: It's for categories as I have categories branched upto 6-7 levels

Comment: Can it be done using graphLookup?